# Alfa AWUS036NH not showing up on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, adapter

When I type `lsusb` I get this as a result:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:56ff Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 5986:0548 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1b96:0f04 N-Trig 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I dont think it is registering the adapter even though its plugged in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is the easy way of solving your problem:

1. Download the driver [here](http://www.alfa.com.tw/download.php).
2. With the following parameters:

   - Product Category: Indoor Wireless
   - Product Model: AWUS036NH (Make sure you select this one.  There are others that look similar...)
   - Type of File: Driver
3. Once downloaded, unzip `DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022.tar.bz2`
4. Simply follow the instructions in the `ReadMe` and you'll be up and running in no time.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/723504/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

The Alfa AWUS036NH is currently not supported by the Linux kernel.  Look at [this answer first](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) before you continue!

[According to the hardware manufacturer](http://www.alfa.com.tw/press_c_show.php?sn=5), they've contacted a [reseller](http://store.rokland.com/) that has created [a module](http://www.rokland.com/mask/drivers/awus036nhr-linux.zip) for the AWUS036NH**R**.

Therefore, I would:

1. [create a system back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) of your machine (or if it's a brand new install, get ready to wipe it and re-install)
2. Follow the [reseller’s instructions](http://www.alfa.com.tw/press_c_show.php?sn=5) on how to build the module yourself

This is highly technical stuff, so if you are unable to follow these instructions:

3. buy an [Ubuntu-compatible WiFi](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/search/?query=WiFi) adapter.